# Disabling autocomplete combined with inputmask

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, browser

I'm using the input mask jQuery plugin to provide certain fields with input rules, for example,

```
$(".year").mask("9999",{placeholder:"Y"});
```

but the field does not have its contents selected on focus, contrary to what the plugin documentation implies. So I added another line to my script:

```
$("input[type=text]").focus(function(){
    this.select();
});
```

However, this didn't seem to work either. I played around a bit more, and noticed that the fields were [sometimes] being pre-populated with values by the browser. However, I could not get the autocomplete to turn off, but I suspect that this is why the contents are not being selected - the browser is adding the contents to the field on focus, and this is firing after the jQuery.

How can I turn off the auto-complete from these fields? I tried adding:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

to the individual text fields, but it did not seem to work (testing in Firefox and Chrome). In IE, adding this to the various fields seemed to work, but the input-mask validation did not.

Answer (score 0):

## The solution is simple and working perfectly in all browsers, atleast for me :)

1. Add disabled attribute to the form fields( email, password, etc.)

   ```
   syntax: <input type="text" class="year" disabled />
   ```
2. On Page Load enable the fields after few miliseconds.

   **use the below JS CODE.**

   ```
   function getRidOffAutocomplete(){

       var timer = window.setTimeout( function(){
           $('.year').prop('disabled',false).mask("9999",{placeholder:"Y"});
           clearTimeout(timer);
          },
          800);
   }

   // Invoke the function
   getRidOffAutocomplete();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, try to turn off autocomplete like this:

```
$("input[type=text]").autocomplete("option", "disabled", true);
```